# How to slice into a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have the following data frame:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: index = [('California',2000),('California', 2010), ('New York', 2000),
 ('New York', 2000), ('New York', 2010), ('Texas', 2000), ('Texas',2010)]
In [3]: populations = [33871648, 37253956,189765457,19378102,20851820,25145561
     ...: ]
In [4]: pop_df = pd.DataFrame(populations,index=index,columns=["Data"])
In [5]: pop_df
Out[5]:
                         Data
(California, 2000)   33871648
(California, 2010)   37253956
(New York, 2000)    189765457
(New York, 2010)     19378102
(Texas, 2000)        20851820
(Texas, 2010)        25145561
```

How can one index into this dataframe to get all of the California data?  I tried the following and got a key error `pop_df[('California,)]` . So then I executed the following and still got a key error:

```
In [6]: index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
In [7]: pop_df2 = pop_df.reindex(index2)
In [8]: pop_df2
Out[8]:
                      Data
California 2000   33871648
           2010   37253956
New York   2000  189765457
           2010   19378102
Texas      2000   20851820
           2010   25145561

In [9]: pop_df2['California']

pop_df2['California']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'California'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-18a1a54664b0> in <module>
----> 1 pop_df2['California']

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'California'
```

What is the right way to index into a multiindex dataframe?

Comment: I would argue that this is a well posed question...

Comment: @anky the `...: ]` actually comes from `iPython`, not the data itself. OP did make one mistake that `index` has an duplicate item `('New York', 2000)`. Aside from that, it should be replicate-able.

Comment: @anky, @@QuangHoang Yes there was an error in line 2 of the input.  Should be index = [('California',2000),('California', 2010), ('New York', 2010), ('New York', 2010), ('Texas', 2000), ('Texas',2010)]. Apologies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `.loc[]`.  Without it, you are looking for a column named 'California', not an index label.

By the way, you had a typo in your input where you were duplicating an index entry.  Here is the full code.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: index = [
   ...: ('California',2000),
   ...: ('California', 2010),
   ...: ('New York', 2000),
   ...: ('New York', 2010),
   ...: ('Texas', 2000),
   ...: ('Texas',2010)
   ...: ]
   ...: populations = [33871648, 37253956,189765457,19378102,20851820,25145561]
   ...: pop_df = pd.DataFrame(populations,index=index,columns=["Data"])
   ...: index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
   ...: pop_df2 = pop_df.reindex(index2)
   ...: pop_df2.loc['California']
Out[1]: 
          Data
2000  33871648
2010  37253956
```

Comment: @Yefet It took me a few minutes to code/check/write/submit the full answer.  There was nothing when I started.  Perhaps I should have put in a placeholder that just said _Use .loc['California']_ and then filled in the details after I secured the early timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

`df['somename']` looks for columns, `df.loc['somename']` looks for index. You want:

```
pop_df2.loc['California']
```

Output:

```
          Data
2000  33871648
2010  37253956
```

You also have [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) option, which allows slicing on different level, and also keeping the full index hierarchy:

```
# default `drop_level` is True
# which behave like `.loc` on top level
pop_df.xs('California', level=0, drop_level=False)
```

Output:

```
                     Data
California 2000  33871648
           2010  37253956
```

Or `xs` on second level:

```
pop_df.xs(2010, level=1, drop_level=False)
```

gives you:

```
                     Data
California 2010  37253956
New York   2010  19378102
Texas      2010  25145561
```

Comment: I've never seen `xs`.  Could you describe the context around when that solution should be used instead of `.loc`?

Comment: first time i see the xs function super helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try with `IndexSlice`

```
pop_df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[['California'],],]
Out[52]: 
                     Data
California 2000  33871648
           2010  37253956
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. You need to indicate level:

```
pop_df2[pop_df2.index.get_level_values(0) == 'California']

#Output:
                     Data
California  2000    33871648
            2010    37253956
```